# Change langage of voice recognition

Tags: language-setting

I sometimes use voice recognition to write text messages. I'm using it in French but I'm wondering if there's a way to switch easily in English.

It does work by switching whole phone langage in `location+langage` menu but requires a phone reboot.

Do you know if there's a way to switch only voice recognition without restart? Maybe thanks to an appli... I found **HandsfreeSMS** which is in English but I don't know if it worthes the price. And the recognition embeeded in the phone is good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change the language for speech (Microsoft Tellme) without the restart.  I don't remember setting any setting in the phone specific to speech.

If you are a developer writing phone apps, you can change the settings in your app, thus allowing the owner to customize their experience, but that is per application.

Comment: I'm not developper. That's why I'm asking for an existing app...